# Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray<GKPlayer *> *' to parameter of type 'NSArray<NSString*> * _Nonnull'

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

```
- (void)lookupPlayers {
    NSLog(@"Looking up %lu players...", (unsigned long)match.players.count);

    // Error on the below line
    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:match.players withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) { {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving player info: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            matchStarted = NO;
            [delegate matchEnded];
        } else {

            // Populate players dict
            self.playersDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:players.count];
            for (GKPlayer *player in players) {
                NSLog(@"Found player: %@", player.alias);
                [playersDict setObject:player forKey:player.playerID];
            }

            // Notify delegate match can begin
            matchStarted = YES;
            [delegate matchStarted];

        }
    }];
```

Comment: Which line does the error message occur on?  While the error isn't exactly plain English, it is reasonably clear; you are sending an array of `GKPlayer` objects to a method that is expecting an array of `NSString` objects

Comment: @Paulw11 The error is commented in the code.

Comment: Oh right.  I hate it when people do that.  I never notice the grey text.

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs for `GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:withCompletionHandler:`. The array of identifiers needs to be an array of `NSString` but you are passing in an array of `GKPlayer`.

You can do this to get an array of player ids from the array of players:

```
NSArray *playerIds = [match.players valueForKey:@"playerID"];
```

Then pass `playerIds` instead of `match.players` to `loadPlayersForIdentifiers:withCompletionHandler:`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept helpful answers to indicate that your question has been solved.